# Getting error while creating kafka topic from command line The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

Hi Folks I am trying to create a kafka topic using kafka-topic command-line tool, but it is kept on showing "the syntax of the command is incorrect" I am using Kafka version 2.5.0 (Commit:66563e712b0b9f84)
below are the commands that I tried but each time I am getting the same error.

```
 1.  .\kafka-topics.bat  --bootstrap-server broker:9092 --topic topic1 --create --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
 2.  .\kafka-topics.bat --create --topic ngdev-topic --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3
 3. .\kafka-topics.bat -create -zookeeper localhost:2181 -replication-factor 1 -partitions 1 -topic sql-insert
 4. .\kafka-topics.bat  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic test1 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is `kafka-topics --create`, which has sub-arguments. Attempt 3 shown is the closest, but only uses one dash for all arguments instead of two.

Next, you give the topic name `--topic X`

Then, give the cluster connection string, ideally using `--bootstrap-server` since the Zookeeper flag is deprecated

Then `replication-factor` is optional, and will use the value defined in the server.properties file for all topics. Same for `partitions`, but it's always good to set this

Overall, [don't run Kafka on windows outside of WSL2](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/)

Comment: Thanks for the response I tried to correct the command like 
 .\kafka-topics.bat --create --topic firsttopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 but still getting same error.

Comment: Then I think you have some other issue with your JAVA_HOME variable, perhaps and the bat file is bailing out... Or `-` and `–` and `—` are all different characters, and you should use the first one... Like I said, though, run Kafka in WSL2 and use the sh files

Comment: now after trying some tuts I am able to print java dir in WSL  
command  -> echo $WSLENV
output-> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin

but still when I am trying to run java --version ,it is saying I need to install jdk

Comment: I don't know what $WSLENV is supposed to be, but $JAVA_HOME should not include the bin directory and WSL2 is Unix based, so shouldn't be using Windows executable paths (Program Files)